# Setting a default dropdown list value in a cascading select from a database

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a cascading select up and running. I want it that when I click a country only its relevant areas will be displayed. 
Now that works until I submit a form. Once the form is submitted, the value from the newly created area list is set to the default that is set before the list is populated.

Before Submitting :
[image: Before Submitting]
After Submitting :
[image: After submitting]

I want it to work similar to this form of list : [Link To Example of choice being the default of a dropdown list](http://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=Junior%20Php%20Developer&Location=2&Category=&Recruiter=Company&Recruiter=Agency) If you click link 1 you will see that a location of 'Carlow' is set. When you click on that dropdown its starting point is Carlow. I have attempted two jquery functions. 1. populates the second list with the choice of the first and 2. is an attempt at sending the second choice aswell as the country to try and set it as a default.

I currently have a getoptions.php file :

```
$sql = "SELECT area FROM Country ORDER BY county ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($state = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $area =$state['area'];
    //get the location if it is set, if not set let it be null
    $location = isset($_GET['location']) ? $_GET['location'] : NULL;

    $selectedString = "";
    if($location && ($area == $location)){
        $selectedString = "selected";
    }

    echo "<option $selectedString value='$area'>$area</option>";
}
```

And the main page :

```
    <select name="location" id="location">
       <option>Please choose a location</option>
    </select>
<script>
$("#country").on('change', function() {
    var country = $(this).val();
    $("#location").load("/getoptions.php?country="+country);
});
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
    var country = $('#country').val();
    var location = $('#location').val();

    $("#location").load("/getoptions.php?country="+country+"&location="+location);
});
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're looking to do? You have one dropdown populated with countries, when you select a country it populates the second dropdown with areas? What are you looking to set as default?

Comment: @Peck3277 Im trying to make the second drop down list have the selected location as its default once its submitted.
so for example if I have : Dublin, Belfast , Antrim
And i select Belfast. Then on the next page the drop down list default should be Belfast. When instead as you can see above the list only has the selected value as an entry once its submitted

Answer (score 0):

Does this help a bit? It should hand back all areas, and if a location parameter is set it should select that location.

```
//I'm assuming your table is set up something like this
//id    |    country    |    area

//This code checks if there's a country parameter set and if there is
//it uses gets all the areas for that country
$country = (isset($_GET['country']) ? $_GET['country'] : NULL;
$sql = "SELECT area FROM Country ";
if($country){
    $sql.= " WHERE Country.country = '$country' "
}
$sql.= "ORDER BY county ASC";


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($state = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $area = $state['area'];

    //get the location if it is set, if not set let it be null
    $location = (isset($_GET['location']) ? $_GET['location'] : NULL;

    $selectedString = "";
    if($location && ($area == $location)){
        $selectedString = "selected";
    }

    echo "<option $selectedString value='$area'>$area</option>";
}
```

If you go to the above file in the browser with url:

```
www.site.com/getoptions.php?country=Ireland&location=Dublin
```

It should output something like the following:

```
<option value="Antrim">Antrim</option>
<option value="Armagh">Armagh</option>
<option value="Dublin" selected>Dublin</option>
```

If you get the above out put you're on the right track. If not there's an error with the php.

On your main page try something like this:

```
<select id="country">
    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
</select>

<select id="location">
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#country").on('change', function() {
        var country = $(this).val();
        $("#location").load("/getoptions.php?country="+country);
    });

    $("#submit").on('click', function() {
        var country = $('#country').val();
        var location = $('#location ').val();
        $("#location").load("/getoptions.php?country="+country+"&location="+location);
    });
}); //doc ready
```

See if that puts you on the right track.

Comment: Is my jquery function correct in sending the location and country values?
If it is, it doesnt seem like your code is working for me.
The idea is just to get the whole drop down list back and set a default value after submitting the form.

Comment: I have played around with the code. However Im getting the same results. When I use your submit jquery function the areas are never displayed .

If I remove the jquery submit and the selectedString part of get options then it leaves the code in the same state it was in earlier.

Comment: If the selectedString is left in then it doesnt print any areas either

Comment: since fixed the selected string problem. There is a typo ahead of isset. However its not setting the default value with the selectedString

Comment: have it echoing out the selected value using the url. It wont set the value as the default after the form submits though